# javascript stack blow up

Tags: javascript, stack

This [article](http://simonwillison.net/2009/nov/23/node/) says the following code will blow up the stack:

```
function fetchLatest() {
  $.getJSON('/wait?id=' + last_seen, function(d) {
    $.each(d, function() {
      last_seen = parseInt(this.id, 10) + 1;
      ul.prepend($('<li></li>').text(this.text));
    });
    fetchLatest();
  });
}
```

> the client-side JavaScript simply uses jQuery’s getJSON method to
>   perform long-polling against a simple URL endpoint
>   Doing this recursively is probably a bad idea since it will eventually
>   blow the browser’s JavaScript stack, but it works OK for the demo.

Is this even true? If so how can we prevent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not true.

Because `getJSON` is asynchronous, the next `fetchLatest()` call will start some time after the previous one finishes.

If you write synchronous code like that, it will freeze, then throw a stack overflow.